# Word for person prying on my personal stuffs

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

which adjective can I use to describe my neighbor, who is always trying to keep eye on my personal matters like what am I bringing from market or what am I cooking etc?

Regards,

Comment: I'd recommend asking a question like this on the Stack Exchange site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)... have you visited there yet?

Comment: No, I just came to know about this from your comment. Thanks!

Comment: The question is closed, so I can't answer. There are a lot of words mentioned here, but I didn't see pry or prying.
Just adding that to the list.
The expression would be "The neighbour's prying eyes".

Answer (score 4):

There are [many words](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nosey-parker) to describe such a person: *Nosey Parker*, *busybody*, *meddler*, *quidnunc*, etc.

Comment: All these are for the situation where the other person is openly intrusive in to your affairs. 'to snoop' is behind your back.

Answer (score 4):

For an adjective, try ***nosy***.

For a verb, try ***snoop***.

From NOAD:

> **snoop** to investigate or look around furtively in an attempt to find out something, esp. information about someone's private affairs
>
> **nosy** (of a person or their behavior) showing too much curiosity about other people's affairs

Answer (score 1):

*inquisitive*, *curious*, or *snoopy* can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping an eye on *you*? The perfect expression for this person is "became your shadow".

Answer (score 1):

In Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, the person you describe is called a *neb*.  The adjectival form is *nebby*.

> A. My neighbor is such a neb.  He's always prying into my business.
>
> B. I hope you won't think I'm being nebby, but what did you buy at the market today?